# What does _._ mean in a package?

Tags: nuget

I suppose this has been asked many times, but I cant find it.

But what dies *.* mean in a package lib folder?

Answer (score 3):

> They are placeholder files to denote an empty directory. Empty directories are often not well-supported in ZIPs so a file with that name is placed in there to ensure the directory is created.
>
> This is important because the existence of an "empty" net46 folder means that the package supports .NET Framework 4.6, but does not require any assemblies (DLLs) in order to run on that version of .NET. This is most likely because the implementation of the package is in the GAC.

(Eilon Lipton, https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/744#issuecomment-123411563)